# WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'tmp'

Tags: python

```
import os

def create_temporary_directory(path, name):
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(path, name)):
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(path, name))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    name = 'tmp'
    create_temporary_directory('..', name)
    os.chdir(name)

print os.getcwd()
```

when i tried to run this program, i'm error "WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'tmp'"

Comment: Well, yeah, you're trying to create a folder one directory above where you are and then change your active directory to one in your current directory.

Answer (score 0):

`os.chrdir(name)` tries to reach `'./tmp'`, but you created your directory at `'../tmp'`

just update your code that way :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    name = 'tmp'
    create_temporary_directory('..', name)
    os.chdir(os.path.join('..',name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do this:

```
import os

def create_temporary_directory(path, name):
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(path, name)):
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(path, name))
    return  os.path.join(path, name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    name = 'tmp'
    path = create_temporary_directory('..', name)
    os.chdir(path)
    print os.getcwd()
```